# Start DnSpy and immediately attach to process

Tags: c#, dnspy

I'd like to use DnSpy as a debugger with my homegrown C# IDE. I'd like to be able to start DnSpy programmatically from my IDE and automatically attach it to the process that executes the compiled user code.

A quick look at `StartUpClass` class seems to suggest there are no command line arguments so it looks like it's not possible out of the box to tell dnspy to immediately attach to a process on start.

Is there a recommended way of going about this, or should I fork the repo and add what I need?

Comment: Latent update: I ended up rolling my own debugger and added it directly into my IDE. I started with Mdbg (which relies on ICorDebug). I found MDbg somewhere on GitHub. It was a good starting point but it's old (.NET 2) so anything newer like lambdas, yield, and async aren't handled 100% correctly out of the box.